# How can I solve an ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to solve this little exercise but, I never got the result:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int N;
            double x, y, resultado;

            N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for(int i=0; 1<N; i++)
            {
                string[] wubaluba = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                x = double.Parse(wubaluba[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                y = double.Parse(wubaluba[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if (y == 0.0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Não Existe!");
                }
                else
                {
                    resultado = x / y;
                    Console.WriteLine(resultado.ToString("F3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Somebody can help me to solve this?

Comment: Well first you need to tell us on which line the problem is. Have you tried debugging this code? What input did you use?

Comment: Please give a detailed error message.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; 1<N; i++)` should probably be `for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)`.  If that's not it, as others have said, please provide more information about the error.

Comment: Input is what?  Error is what and where?  You say OutOfRange, but don't say where or what.

Comment: When getting input from the user, you should probably write a prompt string to the console window so they know input is expected (and what kind). And definitely use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, since the input could easily be invalid and throw an exception. But in this case, you need to say what the exact input was that you typed (for `N` and `wubaluba`).

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem was what Greg explained.

Answer (score 1):

You solve it like any other exception as well:

1. configure your IDE to stop on exceptions
2. run the debug build in the debugger
3. wait until the IDE stops with the exception message

You'll have the exact line of code. You'll have the exception text of the ArgumentOutOfRangeException which will tell you the parameter name which is wrong.

And you can inspect the variable values to see which one is the culprit. If, like in your case, you have invisible variables such as the result from `Console.ReadLine()`, refactor that statement and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Before your code tries to access **wubaluba[1]**. You might want to add a code to check if your string array actually has at least 2 elements in it.